# how to create a gallery of 3 X 3 (Col X Row) using bootstrap on Api call

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

using Bootstrap for UI and call a api for images to diplay in 3X3 [Col X Row]
using javascript Async-Await.
 But getting 3 image in colums and not 3 X 3 Grid layout

It can be using  Grid Columns  or using  Flex  In bootstrap 4

I am use Prototyping using Dog Api for Demo purpose.

On click of Button it will display top 15 images on Grid layout in bootstrap

Not getting correct result  image1 below is output I got.
Image1 [image: Image1]

But it should display as Image2 with different Image in grid
Image2
[image: Image2]

```js
const API_URL = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/20';
const randomImgDogs = document.querySelector('.random-dogs');
const loadingImg = document.querySelector('.loading');
const getButton = document.querySelector('.getRandomDog');

loadingImg.style.display = 'none';

async function getRandomDogs() {
  randomImgDogs.innerHTML = '';
  loadingImg.style.display = '';
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json.message);
  json.message.forEach(dogImage => {
    randomImgDogs.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                <img src="${dogImage}" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
  });
  loadingImg.style.display = 'none';
}
getButton.addEventListener('click', getRandomDogs);
```

```css
img {
  margin: 5px;
}

.flex-column {
  max-width: 260px;
}

a svg {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-bold text-center">Random Dogs</h1>
  <p class="lead">Click on Get to see some random dogs Images!</p>


  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg getRandomDog " href="#" role="button">Get Random Dogs Images
            <svg class="bi bi-chevron-right" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M6.646 3.646a.5.5 0 01.708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 010 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 01-.708-.708L12.293 10 6.646 4.354a.5.5 0 010-.708z"
                    clip-rule="evenodd" /></svg>
        </a>
</div>
<!--  -->
<!-- loading  -->
<div class="loading text-center">
  <div class="spinner-border text-dark" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- loading ends -->


<!-- main  start -->
<div class="random-dogs">

</div>
<!-- main ends -->
```

Comment: What does the data transfer have to do with the display in the browser? You have a list of `n` elements (It doesn't matter where this list came from) which should be arranged in a 3x3 grid. Imho that's just a CSS (+markup) problem.

Comment: @Andreas. I tried but get overlap or get same image in all the 3X3 grid or it will not display image 3X3 Grid with different Images.Thanks In Advanced

Answer (score 0):

You're looping the entire container instead of the item itself.

The entire container you're looping:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
       <div class="d-flex flex-column"> <!-- what you should loop. i.e duplicate  -->
           <img src="${dogImage}" class="img-fluid">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

what you should be looping(the item):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
   <img src="${dogImage}" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

You can refactor your code to below code:

```
async function getRandomDogs() {
  const createParentContainer = children => (
    `<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
         ${children}
        </div>
     </div>`
  );
  randomImgDogs.innerHTML = '';
  loadingImg.style.display = '';
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json.message);
  const children = '';
  json.message.forEach((dogImage) => {
    children += `<div class="d-flex flex-column">
                    <img src="${dogImage}" class="img-fluid">
                </div>`;
  });
  randomImgDogs.innerHTML += createParentContainer(children);
  loadingImg.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: @ akolliy Thanks  But it not displaying in Grid layout [3X3].it shows imagesin straight line only or it gets overlaps